# What it takes to update nightly CM12.1 in TWRP?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, twrp

I want to install the latest cm12.1 nightly update, but I am worried about doing something wrong.

The .zip file is already downloaded. My recovery mode is TWRP and I would like to know if I need to wipe, clear, or do something like that in TWRP options.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check Cyanogenmod Forum and Wiki first?

Comment: Yes, but nothing was specific enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using a Cyanogenmod Build from the same developer then you can just go ahead and install the update without wiping anything.

If you're using a stock (based) rom on your device and you want to install cyanogenmod for the first time then you should wipe /system, /data/, /cache, /dalvik cache. This will be a clean install, so all your data may get lost.
As always adviced: Make a backup (in TWRP) first so you're on the safe side. If something goes wrong you don't have to worry and just restore your backup without any hassle. Furthermore you can save your existing application + app data with Titanium Backup from the Playstore and restore them when the installation has finished :)

Comment: Do we manually flash latest nightly over old without wiping anything? thats it?

Comment: @Dr.Andro flashing without wiping anything should work as most custom roms flash and wipe the needed partiotions by themselfes. You can flash it manually or use an OTA application if your custom rom developer provides one - but I recommend to make a backup just in case